# Algorithms topic question

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-definition

I have a question about a business problem that I could not find its appropriate algorithm that can resolve it. Is my question on or off topic ? [the question is here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/need-the-algorithm-that-resolves-my-problem?noredirect=1#comment17995_11159)

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about your question before the community can help answer topicality.  Algorithm questions are generally on topic though.

Comment: I've already put the link to it. I've posted it in wrong place.

Comment: I took a look at your question.  You may have to come up with your own algorithm.  If you try and run into issues, then it would make sense to ask the mods to move your question over here (where you can add the usual details about what you've tried, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that question would be on-topic.  Your question would be stronger if you demonstrate some of the approaches you have tried and the problems you have encountered with them.